# Android: Assign different layout files to a variable ViewBinding object?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

Is it possible to conditionally attach different layout files to the same view binding object?

For example I define a general view binding object in my fragment like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: ViewBinding
```

Then in the onCreateView, I set it based on value passed like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        settingsVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(Constants.SETTIGNS_VISIBILITY_KEY, false)
    }
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_style_horizontal, container,
            false) as FragmentStyleHorizontalBinding
    if(activity != null) {
        val args = arguments
        val isHorz = args?.getBoolean("isHorizontalLayout")
        isHorz?.let {
             if(!it){
                 binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_style, container,
                         false) as FragmentStyleBinding
            }
        }
    }
    setupViews();
    return binding.root
}
```

Is this possible? I'm not able to access the views this way, and I don't want to create two different view binding objects to avoid repeating the code twice for views with click listener.

Comment: I guess you can do it. And to access a particular view, first cast the binding to that particular layout and then access child views.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of that You keep a boolean of a flag for which view is set or you can only check for `instanceOf`(That will be `is` in kotlin), and accordingly cast the `ViewBinding` object to actual binding class before use.

This can get messy So its better you create two separate `Fragments` if your use case allow you to do it . Or you can have Both views in same layout and you can just change the visibility as per need.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private lateinit var binding1: conditionOneLayout
 private lateinit var binding2: conditionTwoLayout

    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(condition_one())
            binding1 =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.condition_one_layout, container, false)
        else if(condition_two())
            binding2 =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.condition_two_layout, container, false)

    .
    .
    .
 if(condition_one()){
        return binding1.root
}
else{
 return binding2.root
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but with that code I can choose the view of one fragment or another. I hope to help you

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            val layout = if (Condition){
                R.layout.your_first_view
            }else{
                R.layout.your_second_view
            }
            val view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false)
            binding = Binding.bind(view)
    
            return binding.root
        }
```